# How to resolve async await function that returns incorrect data until the fourth time

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await

I have this function "fetchAllUsersByLocation" that fetches users within a 20 mile radius of a given geopoint:

```
import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  query,
  where,
  getDocs,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { GeoHash } from "geohash";

function getGeoHashBoundingBox(latitude, longitude, radius) {
  const latDiff = radius / 69; // 1 degree of latitude is approximately 69 miles
  const lonDiff = Math.abs(radius / (69 * Math.cos(latitude)));

  const minLat = latitude - latDiff;
  const maxLat = latitude + latDiff;
  const minLon = longitude - lonDiff;
  const maxLon = longitude + lonDiff;

  const minGeoHash = GeoHash.encodeGeoHash(minLat, minLon);
  const maxGeoHash = GeoHash.encodeGeoHash(maxLat, maxLon);

  return {
    min: minGeoHash,
    max: maxGeoHash,
  };
}

// Assuming you have initialized Firebase and Firestore
export const fetchAllUsersByLocation = async () => {
  console.log("called");
  // Define the given location (latitude, longitude)
  const givenLocation = {
    latitude: 33.1781735,
    longitude: -117.334903,
  };

  // Calculate the geohash of the given location
  const geohash = GeoHash.encodeGeoHash(
    givenLocation.latitude,
    givenLocation.longitude,
    9
  );

  // Calculate the geohash bounding box for 20 miles
  const boundingBox = getGeoHashBoundingBox(
    givenLocation.latitude,
    givenLocation.longitude,
    20
  );

  try {
    // Get the Firestore instance
    const db = getFirestore();
    // Query the collection of users
    const usersRef = collection(db, "users");
    const filteredUsersQuery = query(
      usersRef,
      where("coordinates", ">=", boundingBox.min),
      where("coordinates", "<=", boundingBox.max)
    );

    // Retrieve the filtered users
    const filteredUsers = [];
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(filteredUsersQuery);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const user = doc.data();
      filteredUsers.push(user);
    });
    console.log(filteredUsers); //this is where it is being logged
    return filteredUsers;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

My problem is, that I'm calling it inside of a React component (React Native if it makes a difference), similarly to this:

```
const TestExample = () =>{
  fetchAllUsersByLocation();
  return(<View></View>)
}
```

When I do this, the first three logs only return the "coordinates" field of the users. On the fourth time, it actually logs all the user data. Similar to this:

```
 LOG  [{"coordinates": "9q8yywdq7vbp"}]
 LOG  [{"coordinates": "9q8yywdq7vbp"}]
 LOG  [{"coordinates": "9q8yywdq7vbp"}]
 LOG  [{"coordinates": "9q8yywdq7vbp", displayName: "Test User", age: 66}]
```

I know this has something to do with the way promises are handled, but I can't figure out how to fix this. If I run the function in a useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  fetchAllUsersByLocation();
},[]);
```

It only returns this:

```
  LOG  [{"coordinates": "9q8yywdq7vbp"}]
```

At the moment, I only have one user, so the user being returned is correct.

I have also tried it like so:

```
const newUsers = await fetchAllUsersByLocation();
```

And when I check the value of newUsers, it returns:

```
  LOG  [{"coordinates": "9q8yywdq7vbp"}]
```

Comment: Where is the line of code that does the logging you're talking about?  Without seeing that, we don't have a complete code here to see what's going on as you describe. There should be enough information in the question that anyone can copy and use to observe the same result.  Don't show "similar" code - show the actual code.  It helps to create and provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example).

Comment: Inside of the fetchAllUsersByLocation, I used to console log it but I changed it to a return statement. I re-added it though.

Comment: So you're saying that the document definitely has 3 fields but the log is only printing one of them for the first three invocations?  Keep in mind that we can't see your data and we don't necessarily know the results of the query.

Comment: Yessss that's right, I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with the async logic but I'm not sure what it could be.